# How to fix running Glassfish (in Windows)?

Tags: java, dns, version, glassfish-4

I'm doing a project (in Eclipse) with GlassFish and it throws this error:

GlassFish requires Java SE version 6. Your JDK is version 0.

I ran the glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain command in a terminal but still get the same error.
[image: Run in Command Prompt]
Here is my JDK version:
[image: In Eclipse]
I also try add AS_JAVA path in asenv.conf but it also didn't work . My Java path is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21"

I hope anyone can fix it as it related to "JMS and DDS architectures " Pratical Homework

Comment: Which version of glass fish?

Comment: probably using a (very) old version of Glassfish, that is not able to deal with the changed format of Java version numbers - try with some older Java version, like Java 8 for example

Comment: My glassfish version is 4.1.1, so I don't think it's such an old version

Comment: sorry, maybe I was misled by "requires Java SE 6" ?! (and having the same behavior/problem, but with a different software not correctly *parsing* the changed version format)

Comment: or I was not that wrong... on the Glassfish site, the oldest version listed is 5.1 from Jan. 2019... so searching on Wikipedia we find out that 4.1.1 is from 2015, replaced by 4.1.2 in beginning of 2017; and by coincidence, Java 9 is from late 2017 too... also note [JEP 223: New Version-String Scheme](https://openjdk.org/jeps/223) -- again, I would test with Java 8, based in all that... (9 years is kind of "such an old version" for me)

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish 4.1.1 requires Java 7 or Java 8. From its `README.txt`:

```
0. Prerequisite
===============

GlassFish 4.1 requires Oracle JDK 7 Update 65+ or Oracle JDK 8 Update 5+.
```

The version 4.1.1 was released in 2015, *replaced* by 4.1.2 start of 2017.
The Version-String Scheme was changed with Java 9, released second half of 2017 - [Key Changes in JDK 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-527735CF-44E1-4144-919B-E7D7CC9CDD4D) and [JEP 223: New Version-String Scheme](https://openjdk.org/jeps/223).
So I believe that the version 4.1.1 of Glassfish cannot *deal* with the new Version-String and so the version of Java 21 is not being recognized correctly as indicated by the error message "Your JDK is version 0".